# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Aviation's [second moderator election](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Federico] [image: Jamiec]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5143582340022272/0).

Comment: Voting requires 150 rep. There are currently more than 1400 users that qualify, but only 219 voted. It seems a little low, but maybe it's on par with other Stack Exchange sites. Anyway, congratulations to both!

Comment: @FabioTurati having the reputation does not equal active participation. I tend not to vote in elections of communities where I am not active, could be the same for others.

Comment: Two important notes:  first, the second moderator won by 77 to 68 in the final scoring round, a very narrow margin of just 11 votes.  Second, while Jamiec wins several counting methods like IRV and SVT, he did not win the condorcet method.  In layman's terms that means people who indicated a preference for Jamiec or SMS von der Tann tended to prefer SMS von der Tann 11 to 9.  This is a real life example of why people obsess over vote-counting methods.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301660/why-didn-t-i-get-an-election-notification-in-ios-app?noredirect=1#comment980920_301660) is the reason I didn’t vote

Answer (score 9):

Thank you everyone! :) I'll do my best not to disappoint :)

Comment: I have a feeling that you'll bring emojis to this SE.

Comment: Congrats.  We're all counting on you.

Answer (score 9):

Awesome! Thanks to everyone who voted. I'll also do my best.

Comment: Congrats.  We're all counting on you.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to [tell you both good luck](https://youtu.be/0RMoH55T-oI?t=10s), we're all counting on you.

Comment: Funny video! : )